# Can I get Swype on my Thunderbolt

Tags: swype

I am trying to install swype (by going to their page and entering my e-mail) on my thunderbolt.  But the e-mail I get from them won't show the install link.  Is there another way?

Answer (score 5):

You must be a part of the beta program:

1. Go to http://beta.swype.com/
2. Login
3. Resend the beta email: https://beta.swype.com/android/welcome/?resend=yes
4. On your Android phone, go to the link in the email: https://beta.swype.com/android/get/ It should start downloading the installer to setup Swype.

If you still have problems, you'll need to contact their technical support.

Comment: I am apart of their beta program.  I did go to that link. I then did contact their technical support and they said that they do not support their beta program and to go to the forums :-(  Terrible loop of frustration.

Comment: I get "Sorry this is not an android phone?" when I go to the install page too. . .

Comment: @Zak Are you using the built-in browser and do you have it set to mobile view?  From Google I see that others with Thunderbolts have installed Swype without issue.

Comment: @Zak Hmmm, my coworker has a thunderbolt, I'll see if I can get him to install swype. I have the same problem on my NookColor (says it isn't an android device even tho I am passing android in the user agent).

Comment: The "Sorry this is not an android phone" message means that your user agent for your browser is not set to Android.  I encountered this before, and resetting the user agent back to default solved the problem.